# Should I use aggregation over mapReduce for a sum over time?

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, aggregation-framework, aggregate

For a `reviews` collection I got documents with following schema:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a664ad3f7a901880a17128a"),
    "location" : "11350009624574901029",
    "account" : "113603894122287361289",
    "comment" : "Above par sushi place for the mid-west. Down side: server forgot our order, twice. He was apologetic and did comp our drinks. \n\nP.S. no warm sake......",
    "updateTime" : ISODate("2018-01-17T04:12:13.859Z"),
    "reviewId" : "AIe9_BGlY-BaOO_aND3JZqxJBS1RA3z9eVPZzQSvV3xv13QOiWzAIy3bxebaQBfADIo85qB6DKjJ2L9hDZusd4D6laJpxuQns7pDij3FBbKAAMiGyE7L8s8",
    "starRating" : "THREE",
    "starRatingNumber" : 3,
    "reviewer" : {
        "displayName" : "alpha landingham"
    },
    "reviewReply" : {
        "comment" : "Hey there! Gosh, I'm sorry to hear that your server forgot your order once, let alone twice! I'm also quite surprised to hear about the sake - we never run out of warm sake. I'd love to dig into this a bit further. Would you please email me directly? You can reach me at Sarah@FRG.rest. Kindly, Sarah",
        "updateTime" : "2017-09-25T13:49:20.443714Z"
    },
    "createTime" : ISODate("2017-09-18T22:02:14.348Z")
}
```

I want to know take all the documents and make some grouping by date aggregates, day, week of the year and month. Basically I want to know what was the count of reviews up to some date aggregate.

I tried:

```
[
   {
      "$match":{
         "account":"113603894122287361289",
         "location":"17198095624181011587"
      }
   },
   {
      "$project":{
         "account":1,
         "starRatingNumber":1,
         "updateTime":1,
         "createTime":1,
         "location":1
      }
   },
   {
      "$group":{
         "total":{
            "$sum":1
         },
         "rating":{
            "$avg":"$starRatingNumber"
         },
         "_id":{
            "month":{
               "$month":"$updateTime"
            },
            "year":{
               "$year":"$updateTime"
            }
         }
      }
   },
   {
      "$project":{
         "rating":1,
         "updateTime":1,
         "total":1,
         "date_aggregates":"$_id",
         "date":1,
         "_id":0,
         "createTime":1
      }
   }
]
```

But that's giving only the *sum aggregate per date grouping* instead of the sum up to each date gouping.

For example if I had:

- 2 reviews in January
- 10 reviews in February
- 7 reviews in March

I want to obtain something like:

- 2 reviews up to January
- 12 reviews up to Frebruary
- 19 reviews up to March

Let's say I want the cumulative `COUNT`, how should I modify the aggregation pipeline? Should I switch to a mapReduce approach as the only way to do this instead?

Answer (score 1):

To simplify the solution, let's say that you have a collection like this (for instance as a result of some aggregation stages):

```
db.col.save({ _id: { month: 1, year: 2017 }, total: 2 });
db.col.save({ _id: { month: 2, year: 2017 }, total: 10 });
db.col.save({ _id: { month: 3, year: 2017 }, total: 7 });
```

To calculate cumulative sum for each year you should run below aggregation:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id.year",
            items: { $push: "$_id" },
            totals: { $push: "$total" }
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: { path: "$items", includeArrayIndex: "arrayIndex" }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            year: "$items.year",
            month: "$items.month",
            total: {
                $let: {
                   vars: {
                      arr: { $slice: [ "$totals", { $add: [ "$arrayIndex", 1 ] } ] }
                   },
                   in: {
                       $reduce: {
                          input: "$$arr",
                          initialValue: 0,
                          in: { $add : ["$$value", "$$this"] }
                       }
                    }
                }
             }
        }
    }
])
```

Remarks:

- Initially we need to have the context of all items in one year, that's why we start with grouping (assuming that items are ordered by month)
- `includeArrayIndex` is a special param of [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html) which will assign subsequent numbers to each month (theoretically unnecessary if you have entire year statistics)
- By adding `1` to that index we determine how many totals should be included in our sum for this particular month
- Using [$slice](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/slice/) we can take first `n` elements of an array (which contains totals for all months ordered)
- [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/) is the method we need to calculate a sum of elements in an array